# Manipulating an array without overriding elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make an array of prices and it's logic is contained inside this function

```
function getPrices(qty: number, id: string) {
    let mappedPrices = inCart.map(item => item.price)
    let product = inCart.find(item => item.id === id)

    const itemIndex = mappedPrices.indexOf(product.price)
    const newPrice = qty * product.price

    if (~itemIndex) {
        mappedPrices[itemIndex] = newPrice   
    } else {
      mappedPrices
    }

    console.log(mappedPrices)
  }


//inCart types -- [{name: string, image: string, price: number, id: string}]

//Example = [{name: 'shoe', image: 'shoe.png', price: 30, id: 'shoeid'}]
```

Everytime I console.log it, the changes are made to one number, but the other returns to it's initial value. Any clues on how to solve it?

The getPrice function is called at every single cartItem component

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getPrices(qty, data.id)
  }, [qty])
```

Comment: please add some data for example

Comment: mappedPrice only contains prices, so `mappedPrices.indexOf(product.price)` is a really bad idea in case there is two product with the same price.

Comment: You're completely right, but I couldn't come up up with other solution

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this :

`let mappedPrices = inCart.map(item => item.price)`

Which means your `mappedPrices` is based on the default prices of `inCart`, so each time you call getPrices(), it will only changes the price of the corresponding product.

Either get all prices at once with a foreach over your inCart products, or do a `getPrice()` (singular) method and only get one price.

Of course, you'll choose depending on how you are handling your cart.

Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-bgjmms) and here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const products = [
    {name: 'shoe', image: 'shoe.png', price: 30, id: 1},
    {name: 'boots', image: 'boots.png', price: 25, id: 2}
  ];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const prices = products.map(p => getPrice(5, p.id))
    console.log(prices);
  });

  const getPrice = (qty, id) => {
    const product = products.find(item => item.id === id)
    const newPrice = qty * product.price

    return newPrice;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      This is a template react
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Nothing is overridden here, you just calculate the new price of the current product based on its data.

Comment: What did you edited ? I know what's your needs and I gave you the example, i'll edit with an example to show you :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If this is what you were looking for, don't esitate to tag the answer asaccepted and/or upvote :) Tell me if there's something more you need from this code